# Accumulate values from raster using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, error-000824

I wrote the script:

```
import arcpy
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial")=="Available":
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    print("Spatial")

from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "D:\Semestr 2 MGR\GeoinformatykaB\Cwiczenia\C07\DaneSkryptGISv02\Dane\Orto"
arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa("punkt","OBJECTID","CentrumGdanska.tif","C:/Users/ilona/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/ZonalSt_punkt2","DATA","MAXIMUM")

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
print "end"
```

I have a problem. This script is failed.
This is error:

```
ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
Failed to execute (ZonalStatisticsAsTable).
```

Could anyone check if it works?

The content of the task:

Create a script to accumulate values from the raster. The tool comes with:

- raster
- the point from which the zone will rise
- barrier value of the maximum sum of values obtained from raster cells.

Comment: Your script is quite odd. Of what value is checking out a seat of Spatial Analyst, then checking it in again? You need to make a checkout/check-in sandwich, with your SA functions inside.

Comment: I check for value: [link]( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HLB8CZEyyKdl19zrzdMqvvUwPO5DSJY7). I changed the order in the script of values: arcpy.CheckInExtension ("Spatial")

Comment: When you run the code do you see the word "Spatial" get printed in the command line window to prove that the extension was checked out?

Comment: Yes, "Spatial" is printed. [LInk](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ufW-WvhAfitJuaMUTjN5Kt7RI-GhzbLM)

Comment: @user2856  I changed what you wrote and printed the word "End"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ZonalStatisticsAsTable` instead of `arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa`.

The `ZonalStatisticsAsTable` function is  part of the `arcpy.sa` package and was imported with `from arcpy.sa import *`

Also use `env.workspace = r"D:\etc...` i.e a raw string r"" or double (escaped) backslashes or single forward slashes instead of single (unescaped) backslashes.